# Differrence between drawn & created functionalities of VLayout SmartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I've found three functionalities in VLayout:

```
vLayout.isDrawn()
vLayout.isAttached()
vLayout.isCreated().
```

These functionalities are inherited from its super classes. Can anyone tell me the difference between the three? Or when the VLayout is said to be drawn, created, attached?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding this three properties are inherited from different superclass:
isAttached from Widget
isCreated from BaseWidget
and isDrawn from Canvas 
We are going from close to the dom to a DHtml object(the canvas)
To me created mean the Widget had been instanciated, attached would mean that the rendered html elements are attached to the dom and drawn when the whole set of element representing a widget is on the screen. It's only my perception, I never found any details on that. These properties don't seem to be for high level operations...

Regards

Alain